# ExtJS class naming conventions

Tags: javascript, extjs, naming-conventions

What are the naming conventions for classes in ExtJS?

I have seen models being named `MyAPP.model.PersonModel` or `MyAPP.model.Person` the same with the file `model/PersonModel.js` or `model/Person.js`

So, what are the conventions for models, views, controllers, utility classes, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have "model" word in the class path, so I am pretty sure you do not need to mention it two times. As a rule: models are singular and stores which are using these models have the same name as model but in plural: model.Person -> store.Persons
Controllers has the same name as the views plus Controller postfix: Panel -> PanelController.
Controller aliases: better to use full path as a name with '-' or '_' delimiters: myApp.view.MainController -> myApp_view_maincontroller or without myApp.. depends..